# text in UIActivityviewcontroller non-editable

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, sharing

I Made a game where the player can share its highscore with an UIActivityviewcontroller. But when pressed share with facebook for example, there comes a screen where the player can edit the text that I have set, So if I set level 9, the player can change it self to level 120.. How can I avoid this?

The piece of code I am using for the sharing:

```
   let text = "I made it to level /(level)!"
    let actviewcon = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text], applicationActivities: nil)
     self.presentViewController(actviewcon, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use UIActivityViewController and permit a built-in activity like Facebook, you cannot alter or prevent the user's interaction with that activity's built-in interface.

So, if you don't like that, and you want to allow the user to post to Facebook, you would need to provide your own interface for doing that. You can post directly to Facebook yourself on the user's behalf thanks to the Accounts framework which lets you employ the user's credentials without seeing them.